# Wix Web Installer: Set homepage in internet explorer and firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, wix, set

i created a web setup by using wix, now i want to set internet explorer homepage and want to add my webpage as favourite with my webinstaller. can any one tell me how to do this in wix (3.0-3.5), i google this but can't find any thing.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a custom action.